A question on measure zero sets in Folland
I'm reading Folland's Real Analysis and don't get how exactly " from which it follows" part: I mean what about sets with measure zero which are not in $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$?
1.21 Theorem. If $E \in \mathcal{L}$, then $E+s \in \mathcal{L}$ and $r E \in \mathcal{L}$ for all $s, r \in \mathbb{R}$. Moreover, $m(E+s)=m(E)$ and $m(r E)=|r| m(E)$.
Proof. Since the collection of open intervals is invariant under translations and dilations, the same is true of $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$. For $E \in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$, let $m_s(E)=m(E+s)$ and $m^r({E})=m(r {E})$. Then $m_s$ and $m^r$ clearly agree with $m$ and $|r| m$ on finite unions of intervals, hence on $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ by Theorem 1.14. In particular, if $E \in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $m(E)=0$, then $m(E+s)=m(r E)=0$, from which it follows that the class of sets of Lebesgue measure zero is preserved by translations and dilations. It follows that $\mathcal{L}$ (the members of which are a union of a Borel set and a Lebesgue null set) is preserved by translation and dilations and that $m(E+s)=m(E)$ and $m(r E)=|r| m(E)$ for all $E^{\prime} \in \mathcal{L}$.

Any set of measure zero is contained in a Borel set of measure zero. Use that.

@Mark yeah in that case because it is a complete measure we are done but this is not in the book.
